# What if I add record while compaction is In Progress for Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

I am new to Cassandra. I have little huge key space(around 1GB).I am adding 10000 records into that keys pace using loop. What will happen if the compaction job is kick started for the key space which I am currently adding records?. Whether the record insertion will be paused in the middle of loop or some other scenario will happen?..
thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compactions happen in the background and will not affect the loading of your data.